# Python MySQL could no process parameters

Tags: python, mysql

Hello everybody i am Trying to do a Update statment with the python mysql connector but i allways get the error

mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Could not process parameters: int(633671912411), it must be of type list, tuple or dict

i have tryed with oder binding types but this also dont work

i dont have a clue why i get this error .

Code:

```
 cursor.execute("""Update users set CARDSN = :id where Username = :username """, id,username)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do not use reserved names or functions like `id()` for variable names. Use specific names like `user_id`

As the error says: Arguments must be supplied list, tuple or dict, not one by one. Since you specify keyword arguments, you need a `dict`:

```
 cursor.execute("""Update users set CARDSN = :id where Username = :username """, {'id': id, 'username': username})
```

Comment: Thank i thinh i get it but now i get the error             
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement

Answer (score 0):

As the error message is telling you, your data "must be of type list, tuple or dict".

If you look at [this example](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html), the `data` variable is a tuple.

```py
#The SQL statement, don't mind it
insert_stmt = (
  "INSERT INTO employees (emp_no, first_name, last_name, hire_date) "
  "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"
)

# Here data is a TUPLE of 4 elements
data = (2, 'Jane', 'Doe', datetime.date(2012, 3, 23))
cursor.execute(insert_stmt, data)
```

In your case, you probably just need to put the parenthesis around `id, username`.
What you are currently doing is calling the function `execute` with **3** parameters : Your SQL statement, the variable `id` **AND** the variable `username`. The framework is waiting for 2 parameters : the statement and the data. You need to put your id and username inside **one single variable**, that is a tuple, dict or list.
This could be :

```py
my_dict = {'id': id, 'username': username}
cursor.execute(statement, my_dict)
```

Or if you don't want intermediate variables :

```py
 cursor.execute("""Update users set CARDSN = :id where Username = :username """, {'id': id, 'username': username})
```

Comment: Thank you but ive tried it with the "dict" and without it but it get the following error any idea how to fix this ?    Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement